# the nonisomorphic subgraphs of K_3 and drawing them

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I believe its 6 although I'm unsure. 
how I thought about it is if I take K_3 and give it three points a, b, c then the only isomorphic graph is trivial. A B and C are vertices in k_3 and - means there is an edge between them the subgraphs I can imagine are

A - B, 
A - C,
B - C,
A,
B,
C,
a total of 6
am I correct?

Comment: One graph by itself cannot be isomorphic. Being isomorphic is a relation between two or more things (graphs, in this case). "The only isomorphic graph is trivial" doesn't really make sense, it has to be isomorphic _to something_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subgraphs of $K_3$ fall into 8 different isomorphism classes. The nonempty ones aredepicted in the following image.

[image: the isom classes of K3]

Comment: @Arthur right -.-

Comment: So which graphs should I be drawing?
- One instance of the trivlal
- One instance of 2 vertices
- One instance of 1 vertex
Also why have you drawn dashed lines sometimes and sometimes full lines. I'm not sure I'm understanding the difference between some of your pictures

Comment: I would draw one of each class. Dashed lines where meant to indicate missing edges, since I found the image difficult to read otherwise.

Comment: so for example on the last 3 rows
The last example is a single point
the second to last is 2 different points
and the third to last is 2 different points but they are connected by an edge?

I think I get it. thanks man. I totally overlooked all of these

Comment: Yes that is correct. No worries I missed half of them on the first try as well...

Comment: Oh and one more thing.
You said there are 8 isomorphisms but i only count 7 in your picture. Is the eight supposed to be 0 vertices?

Comment: Yes it is because I missed the empty subgraph (no vertices no edges) :/